# How to find the define of Prefix in struct StrorageValue?

Tags: pallet

[image]

[image]

As shown in these two pictures, I want to know the exact meaning of "Prefix" in the struct StroageValue, so I go to core::marker file by follow rust-analyzer's guidance, and search the word "Prefix", but got nothing. So could anyone tell me why? And how to find the accurate define of the "Prefix" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the pallet level, `Prefix` is a generic or you can understand it as a placeholder.

When you finally construct the pallet in `construct_runtime!`, the name is its prefix.

For example, https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/78bff0efb83b8b3cff1d09561c335c9b76504066/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L286. `pallet_balance` use `Balance` as its prefix here.

Actually, it is `twox128(b"Balance")` in storage. It needs one hash.

---

Use [subalfred](https://subalfred.hack.ink/user/cli/storage-key.html) you could easily get the storage key.

Or use PolkadotApps to navigate to the chain state page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I partly understood now.

Comment: If this solve your problem, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: oh, sorry, I didn't found the accept button before.